# Remove event listener from the inside if specified callback function

Tags: javascript

I have a situation, where I want to attach a function with parameters to an event listener, like this:

```
var pauseAudioAt = function(aud, seconds, removeListener) {
    console.log(aud.currentTime);
    // check whether we have passed 5 minutes,
    // current time is given in seconds
    if(aud.currentTime >= seconds) {
        // pause the playback
        aud.pause();
        if (removeListener) {
            aud.removeEventListener('timeupdate', pauseAudioAt);
            showBtn();
        }
    }

}
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
                pauseAudioAt(audio, 18, true);
            });
```

I want to remove the listener as soon as the function invoked? How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass `.removeEventListener()` a reference to the same function that you passed to `.addEventListener()`. One way to do that with minimal change to your existing code would be to name your (currently anonymous) function expression, then pass that function to `pauseAudioAt()` instead of passing the boolean:

```
var pauseAudioAt = function(aud, seconds, listenerToRemove) {
    console.log(aud.currentTime);
    // check whether we have passed 5 minutes,
    // current time is given in seconds
    if(aud.currentTime >= seconds) {
        // pause the playback
        aud.pause();
        if (typeof listenerToRemove === "function") {
            aud.removeEventListener('timeupdate', listenerToRemove);
            showBtn();
        }
    }    
}

audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function listener1() {
    pauseAudioAt(audio, 18, listener1);
});
```

That way, `pauseAudioAt()` doesn't need a hardcoded reference to which function needs to be removed.

If you want to call `pauseAudioAt()` *without* removing the listener then just omit that argument: `pauseAudioAt(audio, 18)` -
 or pass `false` or `null` or something if that's more convenient: `pauseAudioAt(audio, 18, null)`.

(If you want to be able to call `pauseAudioAt()` from some other part of your code *and* remove the listener then you could combine this with a function declaration as shown in [Jaromanda X's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45364426/615754).)

Answer (score 0):

You can only remove exactly the same function you've added

in your case you could do

```
// added this
var x = function() {
    pauseAudioAt(audio, 18, true);
}
//
var pauseAudioAt = function(aud, seconds, removeListener) {
    console.log(aud.currentTime);
    // check whether we have passed 5 minutes,
    // current time is given in seconds
    if(aud.currentTime >= seconds) {
        // pause the playback
        aud.pause();
        if (removeListener) {
            aud.removeEventListener('timeupdate', x); // changed this
            showBtn();
        }
    }

}
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", x); // changed this
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use named function.

```
var pauseAudioAt = function(aud, seconds, removeListener) {
    console.log(aud.currentTime);
    // check whether we have passed 5 minutes,
    // current time is given in seconds
    if(aud.currentTime >= seconds) {
        // pause the playback
        aud.pause();
        if (removeListener) {
            aud.removeEventListener('timeupdate', onTimeUpdate);
            showBtn();
        }
    }

}

audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", onTimeUpdate);

function onTimeUpdate() {
    pauseAudioAt(audio, 18, true);
}
```

It'll remove the handle `onTimeUpdate` for event `timeupdate`.